# In C#, a class could return two different types of objects, need to loop through them

Tags: c#

I'm not new to C# but I haven't really used generics and DI much but I've come across a project to teach myself so I'm taking this opportunity. Here's the scenario (will be long and I thank you for your patience)...

We have an on-prems solution which hosts webservices. I have an app that will hit these webservices to pull information and generate data files for one of our partners.
We're moving from the on-prems solution to a cloud-based solution (same vendor, same webservices, slightly different implementation in the cloud).
I decided it would be best to learn interfaces (more than I know now), generics (which I'm learning as I type this), and dependency injection (also a beginner in this specific area) by doing the following

Create an interface for each webservice I'm calling i.e. IGetUsers with a function CallUserService returning List
Implement the interface once each for the cloud solution and on-prems solution

```cs
public class GetUsersCloud : IGetUsers { public List<string> CallUserService(int ID)... }

public class GetUsersPrems : IGetUsers { public List<string> CallUserService(int ID)... }
```

Now I have a class with a constructor that takes an instance of IGetUsers

```cs
public class GetUsers {        
    private IGetUsers _getUsers;
    public GetUsers(IGetUsers getUsers) {
        _getUsers = getUsers;
}
```

From here I can either instantiate this class with an instance of the class that handles the on-prems solution or the cloud solution and call a

```cs
GetUsers getUsers;
if (!cloud) {
     getUsers = new GetUsers(new GetUsersPrems());
} else {
     getUsers = new GetUsers(new GetUsersCloud());
}
List<string> userList = getUsers.CallUserService(5);
```

This works great because my return type is a List so I can handle this very easily. Here's where I'm getting slightly stuck.

I have another interface to implement but the webservice that the classes that will implement it will return different types. What I mean is that while the two webservices will return a type called UserDetailList, they're coming from two different strongly typed classes created by importing the service references from the on-prems and the cloud solution. To handle this, I created an interface with a function that returns a generic

```cs
public interface IUserDetails {
    T GetUserDetails<T>(int ID);
}
```

My class implementations look like this (clearly missing the meat and potatoes but you get the idea)

```cs
public class GetUserDetailsCloud : IUserDetails {
    public T FetchUserDetails<T>(int ID) { 
          CloudWS.UserDetailList userDetailList = cloudWebservice.GetUserDetailList(ID);
          return (T)(object)userDetailList;
    }
}

public class GetUserDetailsPrems : IUserDetails {
    public T FetchUserDetails<T>(int ID) { 
          PremsWS.UserDetailList userDetailList = premsWebservice.GetUserDetailList(ID);
          return (T)(object)userDetailList;
    }
}
```

I create a class with a constructor that takes an instance of IUserDetails

```cs
public class GetUserDetails{        
    private IUserDetails _getUserDetails;
    public GetUserDetails(IUserDetails getUserDetails) {
        _getUserDetails= getUserDetails;            
    }
}
```

Now it's easy, I can instantiate based on whether I'm on cloud or not:

```cs
GetUserDetails getUserDetails;     
object userDetailsResults;
if (!cloud) {
     getUserDetails = new GetUserDetails (new GetUserDetailsPrems());
     userDetailsResults = getUserDetails.FetchUserDetails<PremsWS.UserDetailList>(ID);  
} else {
     getUserDetails = new GetUserDetails (new GetUserDetailsCloud());
     userDetailsResults = getUserDetails.FetchUserDetails<CloudWS.UserDetailList>(ID);
}
```

This is where I get stuck. Since the two webservices have different types, I call it and pass the type based on whether I'm cloud or not and then my results are stored in an object instead of being a instance of the strongly typed class. My next steps involve looping through the results and performing operations/populating an output file. I used to be able to say, with the one type...

```cs
foreach (PremsWS.UserDetail in userDetailsResults) {
    <do some trivial stuff here>
}
```

Now It seems to me that I'd have to write two separate functions to loop through the data and process the results. I feel like there should be a way for me to write a function that takes in a generic type and then depending on what it is (whether an instance of the cloud or on-prems), process the results.

I've been sitting here trying to figure it out and my google has failed me on finding a tutorial or anything that could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: At the second code block (`public class GetUsers`...), I started having to read at quarter-speed because the names are too similar, and it gets worse in the next block. Separate the types into logical layers, name the layers, and give the types in each layer related names. You may know the system well enough for this not to be an issue but the poor schmuck who inherits it from you won't likely fare as well, even with it completed and working. Next, an IoC container should be giving you a `GetUsers` instance and passing to its constructor a `GetUsersPrems` or `GetUsersCloud` instance.

Comment: Understand and this is just mock-up code. My real code is nowhere like this (it has real names that clearly define their purposes).  I guess my question here, summed up, is can i do a foreach with two generics meaning foreach (T child in D parent) { } or do I eventually need to write two loops against the strong types?

Comment: Not with the two implementations returning different types. You need to wrap them in a facade.

Comment: Ah well. I was hoping that wasn't the case and that I was just missing that extra bit of knowledge. Looks like that's what I'm going to do. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Good luck. Maybe you can use one service's types as the outwardly visible types and write a facade around the other to use those types.  It's not ideal but it might save you some work, at least until you get it working.

Comment: That's what I'm hoping to do ultimately. The types are so very similar but since I'm consuming two different SOAP webservices, the return types are different (but not by much). If I could figure a way to cast the on-prems type to the cloud type or vice versa it would make life super simple but I feel like that would be a very big time sink.

Comment: Can one assume that you aren't the maintainer of these webservices? You refer to them as "cloud-based" and "on-prems" but there's more to it than just where they're hosted, right? Clearly they're two different service definitions, which is really why this is an issue.

Comment: could you use an if conditional to check for the existence of a property within the type and route `if` `else` based upon the existence of said property?  You would have to do `foreach (object obj in userDetailsResults) 
{ 
    if (obj.SomeProperty != null) 
    { //do something 
    }
     else { // do something else 
      }
}` ?  forgive me if I misunderstood the question

Comment: @madreflection correct, I'm not the maintainer. They're closed source products from a vendor.

Comment: @hexagod possibly. I'm going to look at that option tomorrow as my day is wrapping up.  I think the biggest problem though is that the types are damn near identical I imported the webservices into my project as service references so it created strongly typed classes for each webservice.

Comment: You might be able to use something like AutoMapper to deal with the guts of translating the objects so you can focus on the structure of the facade.

Comment: How are you generating the CloudWS.UserDetailList class, if it is through the tools built in to VS to create a service client there is a way to make  the classes inherit a common base class/interface that you could use for your list. See the " Note" in step 4 of [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)

Comment: another thing is you might be able to do `foreach (var obj in userDetailsResults) 
{ 
    if (obj == PremsWS.UserDetailList) 
    { //do something 
    }
     if (obj == CloudWS.UserDetailList) 
     { // do something else 
      }
}`  use a conditional to check the `var` type?

Comment: @hexagod: That's a lot of noise at the call site, and then the method has to return `object` which strips it of semantic value.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal path here would be to just return the same type from `GetUserDetailList`. Since that seems like it isn't an option, considering both return types to be the same name has done a little bit of harm in realizing their separation.

They may as well be returning type `Web` and `Local`. In addition, it would seem you do not have the ability to alter the `UserDetailList` type.

As a result, the only place you can introduce a fix is at the point of consumption. Once you have the strongly typed instance, you will need to abstract over it. The best way here, since you know the properties at least, is to use a copy constructor to facilitate the abstraction.

```
public class LocalUserDetailList
{
    public [[ underlying name and type for the UserList data ]] { get; set; }

    public LocalUserDetailList(PremsWS.UserDetailList UserDetailList)
    {
        // populate the publicly available list above^
    }

    public LocalUserDetailList(CloudWS.UserDetailList UserDetailList)
    {
         // populate the publicly available list above^
    }
}
```

Now you can use this copy constructor in order to return a unified type to consume.

```
public interface IUserDetails 
{
    LocalUserDetailList FetchUserDetails(int ID);
}

public class GetUserDetailsCloud : IUserDetails {
    public LocalUserDetailList FetchUserDetails(int ID) { 
          CloudWS.UserDetailList userDetailList = cloudWebservice.GetUserDetailList(ID);
          return new LocalUserDetailList(userDetailList);
    }
}

public class GetUserDetailsPrems : IUserDetails {
    public LocalUserDetailList FetchUserDetails(int ID) { 
          PremsWS.UserDetailList userDetailList = premsWebservice.GetUserDetailList(ID);
          return new LocalUserDetailList(userDetailList);
    }
}
```

And finally access the unified instance without `object` from your call.

```
GetUserDetails getUserDetails;     
LocalUserDetailList userDetailsResults;
if (!cloud) {
    getUserDetails = new GetUserDetails (new GetUserDetailsPrems());
    userDetailsResults = getUserDetails.FetchUserDetails(ID);  
} else {
    getUserDetails = new GetUserDetails (new GetUserDetailsCloud());
    userDetailsResults = getUserDetails.FetchUserDetails(ID);
}
```

While this does not use generics, it does work, and is easy to read and debug. Sometimes, generics can become sloppy, and in this instance it would be. It would require that you use a properties iteration in order to get the values during iteration had you kept using object as the type. That is not ideal, is slow, and can cause the code to be very hard to read.

In addition, using an abstraction such as this should also allow you to realize places in your code where you can remove the duplication of calls and just return the one copy constructor instance. If you were to then leverage your abstracted version with generics, that would be a much more powerful and integrated way of using that tool.